# mongo-cxx-driver library builds but persistent linking and debug issues

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, visual-studio-2015, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm trying to build the mongo-cxx-driver for use with Cinder on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015.  Cinder uses Boost 1.58, so I built the driver against their included version of Boost.

I tried to follow the instructions exactly as described on github, but the final libs and dlls I get seem to have an issue with them.  I'd love some help debugging where my compilation went wrong!

Here's what I did, mirroring the official instructions [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/)

### Step 1

I followed the instuctions [here](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html) for installing the MongoDB C Driver.  Simply copy/pasting the CMake calls under the Windows Build Instructions worked perfectly.

### Step 2

Since I'm using Windows and Visual Studio 2015, I should use the Boost option for Polyfill.

### Step 3

I untarred the mongo-cxx-driver-3.0.2 that I downloaded from github; then I went into `mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2` and ran CMake:

`cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-cxx-driver -DLIBBSON_DIR=C:\mongo-c-driver -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Cinder\include\ -DLIBMONGOC_DIR=C:\mongo-c-driver -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1 ..`

And then built and installed the project:

```
msbuild.exe ./ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
msbuild.exe ./INSTALL.vcxproj
```

Everything runs great and I get confirmation from CMake that there were no errors.  Hooray!

### Issues

While testing, I tried running the test program

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::printf("Starting mongo-cxx-driver test...\n");
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
    std::printf("End of demo!\n");
}
```

If I run it in Debug, then it crashes after printing out the database with a "Debug Assertion Failed" message:

```
File: minkernel/crts/ucrt/src/appcrt/heap/debug_heap.cpp
Line: 980
Expression: __acrt_first_block == header
```

Checking the breakpoint shows that it causes the error on the line at the end of the file -- probably during cleanup from the line

```
std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl
```

My first suspicion was that perhaps the .lib files and .dll were built for release -- so I built it in release.

I get an error `mongo_test.exe has triggered a breakpoint` with the breakpoint deep inside of `bsoncxx.dll!bsoncxx::v_noabi::string::view_or_value::terminated()`.

While trying to debuge, I change the insertion line to:

```
mongocxx::result::insert_one result = collection.insert_one(document.view());
```

in an effort to collect more debug information.  I was surprised to find that this won't compile with a C2440 error:

```
'initializing': cannot convert from 'boost::optional<mongocxx::v_noabi::result::insert_one>' to 'mongocxx::v_noabi::result::insert_one' mongo_test  C:\mongo_test\src\mongo_testApp.cpp 39
```

I suspect that perhaps the problem is with how I've linked Boost / std::experimental, but I've tried a couple of different variations (disabling using boost and using std::experimental for polyfill instead), but that doesn't seem to create a working library.  Or perhaps there's a mismatch with Debug / Release or x64 vs x86?

Can anyone identify a misstep in this build process?

thanks!

[EDIT] Ran the included tests in mongo-cxx-driver, including the output here for debugging purposes:

```
~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2> MSBuild.exe .\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10/12/2016 3:03:11 PM.
Project "~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj" (1) is building "~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-dr
iver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "x64\Debug\RUN_TESTS\".
  Creating directory "x64\Debug\RUN_TESTS\RUN_TESTS.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Debug\RUN_TESTS\RUN_TESTS.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
PostBuildEvent:
  setlocal
  "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\ctest.exe" --force-new-ctest-process -C Debug
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  :cmEnd
  endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
  :cmErrorLevel
  exit /b %1
  :cmDone
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
  :VCEnd
  Test project C:/Users/nathan lachenmyer/Downloads/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2
      Start 1: bson
  1/3 Test #1: bson .............................***Exception: Other  0.00 sec
      Start 2: driver
  2/3 Test #2: driver ...........................***Exception: Other  0.01 sec
      Start 3: instance
  3/3 Test #3: instance .........................***Exception: Other  0.00 sec

  0% tests passed, 3 tests failed out of 3
  Errors while running CTest

  Total Test time (real) =   0.03 sec

  The following tests FAILED:
          1 - bson (OTHER_FAULT)
          2 - driver (OTHER_FAULT)
          3 - instance (OTHER_FAULT)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-d
river-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\ctest.exe" --force-new-ctest-process -C Debug
\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd\r [~\Downloads
\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mo
ngo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone\r [C:\Users\nat
han lachenmyer\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3
.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.
2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\m
ongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd\r [~\Downloads
\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 8. [~\Downloads\mongo-c
xx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(PostBuildEvent target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx
-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\ctest.exe" --force-new-ctest-process -C Debug
\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd\r [~\Downloads
\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mo
ngo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone\r [C:\Users\nat
han lachenmyer\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3
.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.
2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone\r [~\Downloads\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\m
ongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd\r [~\Downloads
\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 8. [~\Downloads\mongo-c
xx-driver-r3.0.2\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2\RUN_TESTS.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.71
```

Comment: Are you able to try the 3.0.2 driver and Boost 1.59?  We've had reports of success on MSVC with that combination.

Comment: Are there known issues with MSVC when using the 3.0.1 driver and Boost 1.58?

Comment: There are no known issues, but we haven't tested that combination specifically, either.

Comment: Trying the v3.0.2 driver resolved the basic builder issues -- I get no unlinked object issues.  But I'm still getting crashes in debug mode and breakpoints in release mode.

Comment: I tried to run the tests, and the build fails all 3 tests.  I rebuilt the mongo-c-driver with version 1.3.4 as per the README, but it still fails.

Comment: Are you building the driver and the application against the same version of the CRT? It must match across the driver and the application. In particular, you must ensure that your application and the driver are either both using the static or dynamic runtime, and that both are consistent w.r.t. the Debug or Release runtimes. You can control which mode you build with via the -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=[Debug|Release] argument: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html

Comment: Note also that it must be consistent between your app, the driver, and any other libraries you link (including boost). I'm not sure how Cinder does its boost build, but you might want to look into that.

Comment: N.B. Looks like this may be moving to the mongodb-user mailing list for more discussion: [C++ Driver builds on Windows, but crashes](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/-A1an7mRmZM/HYacaI8GBAAJ)

Comment: I will be following up to this post on the mongodb-user mailing list, since it was re-posted there.

Comment: I tested this against an independently downloaded Boost 1.58 and Boost 1.60 and received the same issues.  Bummer :(

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I faced it today, so I'll post my solution here to whoever it might interest. It only happens in debug mode, The error stopped when I changed /MD to /MDd. You'll probably have to recompile mongocxx to match your settings.