# Boost.Test crashes with ***Exception: Other on MSVC

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build and run tests using [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/libs/test/index.html) in Microsoft Visual Studio 14 2015 (on AppVeyor).  My testcase is defined like this, so it should always pass and never throw:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE target_boost_test
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testcase)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}
```

In the CMake script I set up linkage for the test as such:

```cmake
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
add_executable(${UT_TARGET} ${UT_SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(${UT_TARGET} ${LIBRARIES} ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})
```

The test compiles fine without any warnings but does not run and fails with a pretty unclear `***Exception: Other`.

```
Test project C:/projects/msvc-boost-test/build
    Start 1: target_boost_test
1/1 Test #1: target_boost_test ................***Exception: Other  0.08 sec
```

<strike>To reproduce easily I have set up a repo on GitHub with all the necessary files and an automated build job on AppVeyor to show the issue.</strike>

Comment: This seems to be related but has no answer: [mongo-cxx-driver library builds but persistent linking and debug issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982310)

Comment: It might be that inconsistent DLL versions are used at build time vs. runtime.  Can you check with e.g. dependency viewer? On linux, there's no issue: https://i.imgur.com/WTNpaBg.png

Comment: @sehe Thank you very much for looking into it.  I don't experience problems on Linux either.  Unfortunately I don't even have a Windows machine but only want to build my project cross-platform using AppVeyor.  I will try to export the build artefact and inspect it on Linux.

Comment: @sehe All libraries seem to be dynamically linked ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K43Fs.png)).  Because I'm running Dependency Walker in Wine, I had to use the x86 version.  Also in Wine, all DLLs are of course missing.

Comment: Why do you have to run it in wine? You mean you don't have access to the test machine? That's gonna make it harder to reproduce the problem. Perhaps lift the build artefacts and run the test manually on a windows system that _is_ at your disposal

Comment: @sehe I found a solution.  The exception was caused by the DLL for Boost.Test not being found.  Now I'm working around it by just copying the DLL to the build directory before running tests.  I wonder whether there is a better solution, e.g. tell the dynamic linker where to look for DLLs.

Comment: Apparently the CMake recipe already did that for me on linux (I usually do that manually on linux). So, you could reasonably expect it to also work on MSVC but perhaps there's a different CMake pattern involved for that. (In Visual Studio just making libraries dependencies should be enough to copy them to the output directory AFAIR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>[Many thanks to @sehe for getting me on the right track]</sub>

---

In this case the exception was caused by the Boost.Test DLL not being found.  I'm too unfamiliar with Windows as to know why the dynamic linker cannot find DLLs automatically.  So far I have found two workarounds/fixes for this situation.  The first is my preferred way.

## 1. Add the DLL path to PATH

In case of my AppVeyor YAML config this looked like this:

```yaml
environment:
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: "C:\\Libraries\\boost_1_59_0\\lib64-msvc-14.0"
  PATH: "%BOOST_LIBRARYDIR%;%PATH%"
```

## 2. Copy the DLL to the same directory

Apparently the dynamic linker always searches the working directory (or the directory of the executable?  I don't know).  Copying the DLL over also worked, again in my AppVeyor YAML config this looked like this:

```yaml
after_build:
  - cmd: copy "%BOOST_LIBRARYDIR%\boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll" .
```

This is the less generic solution, as it requires explicitly specifying the name of the DLL.  Thus, when switching from debug to release mode one also has to adapt the DLL name.

---

The contents of the repo from the question are summarized in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/hmenke/cebf23b56b3f11b07a1b825558eab4b1) in a working version.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use boost test as header-only library by including `<boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>`.

Comment: @VTT Thank you for your input.  For Boost.Test this is indeed a correct and sensible approach but other Boost libraries may not exist header-only and will lead to the same problem.